# XCode: Resize image use aspect ratio and move down elements below image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xamarin.ios, uiimageview

I have stuck with resize image when user change orientation on iPad.

I want to resize image on landscape (aspect ratio) and move down all rows (Views) below that image.

Now when rotate screen image is very stretched.

How to do responsible design when rotate screen?

[image: What I have in Portrait mode]
[image: What I want to get in Landscape mode]

Sorry for noob question I'm new in Xcode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate [viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransitiontosize) in Xcode or use [ViewWillTransitionToSize](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIViewController.ViewWillTransitionToSize/) in Xamarin.iOS to resize the views when rotate screen.

Sample code with Objective-C in Xcode:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    // Code here will execute before the rotation begins.
    // Equivalent to placing it in the deprecated method -[willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:].
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // Place code here to perform animations during the rotation.
        // You can pass nil for this closure if not necessary.
        // Reorganize views, or move child view controllers.
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {

            //Update UI
        }

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {

            //Update UI
        }

    }completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context){
                                     // Code here will execute after the rotation has finished.
                                     // Equivalent to placing it in the deprecated method -[didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:].
                                     // Do any cleanup, if necessary.

                                 }];
}
```

Sample Code with C# in Xamarin.iOS:

```
    public override void ViewWillTransitionToSize(CGSize toSize, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator)
    {
        base.ViewWillTransitionToSize(toSize, coordinator);

        coordinator.AnimateAlongsideTransition((IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) => {

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown)
            {
                //Update UI
            }

            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft|| UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight)
            {
                //Update UI
            }

        }, (IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) => {
            //Transition Completion
        });
    }
```

Comment: @DaleYY, did my answer help you?